# Laravel: how to prevent a MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php when someone access a post-route without giving post parameters?

Tags: laravel, exception, post

Laravel: how to prevent a MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php when someone access a post-route without giving post parameters?

When i define a post route its only accessable by a post request. If i call the url normaly in a browser, it throws an exception. how to prevent this?

Comment: Try adding ```Route::get('yourRouteThatIsNormallyAPostRoute', function() { // do some stuff});``` to the routes.php file.

Comment: Or use `Route::any(...)` instead of `Route::post(...)`

Answer (score 6):

Anyone can do a request to any of your routes using a method that isn't allowed. You can make a view for the exception in the `resources/views/errors` folder. Laravel comes with an error page for the HTTP status code `503` (Service Unavailable Error) by default.

The HTTP status code for the MethodNotAllowedHttpException is `405`, so making a view called `405.blade.php` will cause Laravel to present that view instead of the MethodNotAllowedHttpException message.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job 
This will catch all errors like, MethodNotAllowed or 404(page not found) or ModelNotFound or TokenMissMatch and redirect to any route you desire with proper error!

```
Handler.php

    public function render($request, Exception $e){
       if ($e instanceof ForbiddenException) {
            return redirect()->route('name')->withErrors(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
       }
       return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

Or just for Method not allowed

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
    if ($e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
        return redirect()->route('name')->withErrors(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Route::any()` or `Route::match()`

Example:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function () {
    //
});

Route::any('foo', function () {
    //
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the match and any methods but they were not what I needed.

This is what I did:

1- Added the default error handler in the Base controller. 
2- Called the error manually for each forbidden HTTP METHOD.

[image]

Then, on the BaseController:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

adding  a file  "405.blade.php" into your "resources/views/errors" will prevent the MethodNotAllowedHttpException page from showing up again.

Answer (score 0):

For laravel 9, i solved it this way, you can change the exception to be caught. Make sure to include it at the top:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
```

And:

```
Handler.php

/**
 * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
        //
    });

    $this->renderable(function (MethodNotAllowedHttpException $e, $request) {
            return abort(404, "page not found");
    });
}
```